# How to sort group_by month and year in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, group-by

**pages_controller.rb**

```
@past_challenges_by_years = @past_challenges.group_by { |t| [t.deadline.year, t.deadline.month] }
```

How can I break it down in the view with year and then subdivide it with month like this:

```
2014 # Years
 01 # Months
   Challenge
   Challenge
 02
   Challenge
 08
   Challenge
2016
 03
   Challenge
 08
   Challenge
```

**view.html.erb**

```
<% @past_challenges_by_years.sort.each do |year, challenges| %>
  <%= year %>
  <%= month %> # I don't know how to define this.
  <% for challenge in challenges %>
    etc...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by sorting the keys and then look up the challenges while iterating through those keys.

```
<% @past_challenges_by_years.keys.sort.each do |(year, month)| %>
  <%= year %>
  <br />
  <%= month %>
  <br />
  <% @past_challenges_by_years[[year, month]].each do |challenge| %>
    <%= challenge %>
    <br />
```

Edit: Here is a new solution that only displays years and months once.

```
@past_challenges_by_years.keys.map { |a| a[0] }.uniq.sort.each do |year|
  puts year
  @past_challenges_by_years.keys.select { |a| a[0] == year }.map { |a| a[1] }.uniq.sort.each do |month|
    puts month
    @past_challenges_by_years[[year, month]].each do |challenge|
      puts challenge
    end
  end
end
```

I think it should be simple enough to convert to ERB.

Comment: You will need to style it. I can add some minimal style to my example

Comment: I added some line breaks.

Comment: I added a new answer.